# DKIM Key validation fails when using Mail Command

Tags: email, postfix, dkim, telnet

I have a relay server that I am using to send emails. I am signing outbound emails using dkim. When I send the mail using telnet the gmail logs look like this:

```
 Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of user@test.com designates X.X.X.X as permitted sender) client-ip=X.X.X.X;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@test.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of user@test.com designates X.X.X.X as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=user@test;
```

When I send using the mailx client to the same relay server I get the following:

```
  Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of user@test.com designates X.X.X.X as permitted sender) client-ip=X.X.X.X;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=fail header.i=@test.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of user@test.com designates X.X.X.X as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=user@test.com;
```

I'm confused as to why its returning different results. I am sending emails form the same server as well. Issue happens in yahoo mail as well.

```
This is what my master.cf file looks like:
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd   -v
#  -o content_filter=dksign
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
587       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd   -v
#  -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o content_filter=dksign
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#628      inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# The Cyrus deliver program has changed incompatibly, multiple times.
#
old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=foo argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
```

Main.cf:

```
# RR: Mon Apr 29, 2013 => added 72.172.71.2/32 to support (LA) Duo VPN
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = test1.mpx.test.com
mydomain = mpx.test.com
masquerade_domains = !jetsetter.com !parkandbond.com !testcity.com !testtaste.com !wsjselect.com !mx.test.com !qatools.test.com test.com $mydomain

mynetworks =
XX.XX.XX.XX
XX.XX.XX.XX
XX.XX.XX.XX
$myhostname
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
soft_bounce = no
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
local_header_rewrite_clients = permit_mynetworks
smtp_generic_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/generic
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
smtpd_sasl_application_name = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
#smtpd_enforce_tls = no
#smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
#smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/mx1-cert.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/mx1-key.pem
#smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
#smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/spool/postfix/smtpd_tls_session_cache
#tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
#smtpd_tls_security_level = may
mailbox_size_limit = 102400000
message_size_limit = 51200000
queue_minfree = 76800000
smtpd_client_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unknown_client
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_invalid_hostname,
  reject_non_fqdn_hostname
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unlisted_sender,
  reject_non_fqdn_sender,
  reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unlisted_recipient,
  reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
  reject_unauth_destination,
  reject_unknown_recipient_domain
# check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/filtered_domains
smtpd_data_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  reject_unauth_pipelining,
  permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions =
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
  PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
  xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES
postscreen_upstream_proxy_protocol = haproxy
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mail.mpx.test.com.tld.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mail.mpx.test.com.tld.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
#smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

Comment: did you set your postfix `non_smtpd_milter = $smtpd_milter`

Comment: smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891